# Angular AOT/ngc duplicates route definitions

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-aot

I'm having some trouble setting up ahead-of-time compilation for my lazy-loaded Angular app.

Lazy-loaded routes are defined in an `app.routes.ts` file which is imported by `app.module.ts`. When I run `ngc` the contents of `app.routes.ts` are inlined into `app.module.ngfactory.ts`, but this file also includes an import of the original `app.module.ts`, which then imports `app.routes.ts` again and so on...

When I then bundle the AOT app with Webpack I get a duplication of my route definitions (which use `angular2-router-loader`), with relative paths that do not resolve on one of the two instances (since one is inlined and lives at a different level of my directory tree).

How do I resolve this? It seems strange to me that `ngc` generates an import of the original `app.module.ts` file in `app.module.ngfactory.ts` but I don't know how to prevent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone finds this question, I solved the problem by setting`angular2-router-loader`'s `genDir` option to the directory *within my `genDir` directory* that contains the source files for my compiled application.

The documentation for this option has now been clarified with [an example](https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular2-router-loader/blob/master/docs/options.md#aot-example).